# Calculate target address of mips assembly control instruction

Tags: assembly, mips

Given the assembly instruction:

```
bne $s0, $s1, DONE
```

The address of the instruction is `500` bytes. If the offset field contains the following
value:

```
1111111111110100
```

what is the target address? Explain your answer.

Is the answer to this question : `494`?
My reasoning is that
the offset field in decimal is `-10` but i am not sure about it :(
and the address of pc at this point is `500+4`
so:

```
target address = pc address + (offset)= 504+(-10) = 494.
```

I wanted to know if i am doing it correct or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, except that `1111111111110100` is not -10 in decimal, it's -12. Thus, the target address is 504-12 = 492.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Could you please tell me how to calculate the decimal of this offset field?

Comment: Since the MSB of the offset is `1`, the offset is negative. To convert it to positive: invert all of the bits; add one; then convert to decimal.